# Regex for [[Category:Text|*]]

Tags: java, regex, string

Parsing this text [[Category:sometext]] in java with this regex \[\[Category:(.*?)\]\] which gives me "some text"

But some cases texts coming like this [[Category:sometext|*]] extra characters are "|" pipe and "*" star.

Sometimes both character is coming "text|*" and sometimes only one is coming "text|", "text*" and i can't figure out how to parse it with regex.

Expected result: sometext

Comment: This is unclear - what do you want the result to be in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add those characters after `.*?` and apply the `?` quantifier (one or zero occurrences) to each to make them optional:

```
\[\[Category:(.*?)\|?\*?\]\]
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD9sB0/1)

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/NPoEDS):

```
String s = "[[Category:sometext]]\n[[Category:sometext|*]]\n[[Category:sometext|]]\n[[Category:sometext*]]"; 
String rx = "\\[\\[Category:(.*?)\\|?\\*?\\]\\]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```